# Python Parallelise Simple For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing

I am trying to make the code below run faster. In its current state, it is taking around 5-6 minutes, which is a lot for the occasion. I am working on two pandas dataframes, taking a datetime and an 'instrument' from the `rfqs` dataframe, matching the instrument on the second dataframe and finding the closest date from the second one to the date I took from the `rfqs` dataframe.  The issue is that i'm 1) Iterating over a dataframe, which is not very efficient and 2) the nearest function is probably not very efficient either. So I was wondering, if I can parallelise this loop? Vectorising everything would be great but I'm not very sure about it so that is why I'm leaning more to parallelisation.

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

```
rfqs['reliable_mid'] = 0

print('This will only take 3-4 minutes')
print('Out of',len(rfqs)-1)
for i in range(len(rfqs)):
    
    tempdate = rfqs.iloc[i]['date_time']
    tempins = rfqs.iloc[i]['instrument']
    
    searchspace = mids[mids['instrument']==tempins]
    
    nearestdate = nearest(searchspace['date_time'],tempdate)

    nearestmid = mids[mids['date_time']==nearestdate]['mid']
    
    rfqs['reliable_mid'].iloc[i] = nearestmid.iloc[0]
    print(i,end = "\r")
```

Comment: It may be possible to improve the algorithm, but this is nearly impossible without more information about the computed data (eg. types, size, typical data, etc.) or a *minimal reproducible example*. As for the parallelization, the GIL and IPC often results in pretty bad speed-up. It may worth using multiprocessing if the dataframe are small.

Answer (score 0):

Letting Pandas do its magic by formulating the problem at a higher level of abstraction may already yield the speed-up you're looking for.
I'd create a new column `nearest_date` in `rfqs`, e.g.

```
mids = mids.set_index("instrument") # faster lookup
rfqs['nearest_date'] = rfqs.apply(
  lambda row: nearest(mids.loc(row["instrument"]), 
  axis=1)
```

then merge `rfqs` with `mids`